# SSRS report expression FormatDateTime changes Nulls to '1/1/0001'

Tags: sql-server, ssrs-2016

I have a report where I need to remove the time from a datetime column. 
I've found this expression to work but it changes all the null values to '1/1/0001'

```
=FormatDateTime(Fields!Temperature_Control_Inspection_Date.Value,DateFormat.ShortDate)
```

I have tried the below expression to look for nulls but it doesn't appear to work.

```
=IIF(Fields!Temperature_Control_Inspection_Date is nothing, nothing, FormatDateTime(Fields!Temperature_Control_Inspection_Date.Value,DateFormat.ShortDate))
```

How can I show just the Date from a DateTime column without also having all the nulls replaced by '1/1/0001'?

Comment: Try this one `=IIf(IsNothing(Fields!Temperature_Control_Inspection_Date.Value), "", FormatDateTime(Fields!Temperature_Control_Inspection_Date.Value, DateFormat.ShortDate))`

Comment: Converting my comment to answer. Please upvote/accept so that this does not show up as unanswered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below will work :

```
=IIf(IsNothing(Fields!Temperature_Control_Inspection_Date.Value), "", FormatDateTime(Fields!Temperature_Control_Inspection_Date.Value, DateFormat.ShortDate))
```

Above will have null dates as blank. Also, it will remove the time and just get you the date portion.